# How can I disable dead keys in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have this [Logitech G105 Keyboard](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/g105-gaming-keyboard) and I would like to disable Dead Keys, and still keep the Keyboard's Layout.

I am using `English (US, alternative international)` since it matches my keyboard buttons.

The problem is that no matter what Layout I choose, I still have Dead Keys enabled.

---

Edit 2023: the given answer seems to no longer work...

Some `xev` output

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3801,
    root 0x247, subw 0x0, time 5354294, (54,90), root:(292,308),
    state 0x10, keycode 49 (keysym 0x60, grave), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (60) "`"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (60) "`"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3801,
    root 0x247, subw 0x0, time 5354408, (54,90), root:(292,308),
    state 0x10, keycode 49 (keysym 0x60, grave), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (60) "`"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You will probably get better expertise on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: I tried there, no actual answer. Only "use a keyboard layout without dead keys"

Answer (score 2):

There are two keysyms for grave, `grave` and `dead_grave`, by default `dead_grave` is set to the ` key. xmodmap can be used to change it, and should be in Ubuntu by default (with arch install xorg-xmodmap).

To change it from the default `dead_grave` to `grave`, run:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  49 = grave notsign grave notsign brokenbar notsign brokenbar notsign"
```

The rest of the values are various modifiers, e.g. the second one is shift.

If you want this to be permanent, create `~/.Xmodmap`, and then add just:

```
keycode  49 = grave notsign grave notsign brokenbar notsign brokenbar notsign
```

If there are any other dead keys you're having trouble with, run:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep dead
```

And it should give you a list of dead keys. Alternatively you could run:

```
xmodmap -pke >> ~/.Xmodmap
```

You will then have a full list of keyboard keys and their sym values in `.Xmodmap`, which makes it easy to change your dead keys and any other keys to whatever custom layout you like.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: This no longer appears to work in 22.04.  I have `$ xmodmap -pke | grep grave
keycode  49 = grave notsign grave notsign brokenbar notsign bar bar grave notsign bar bar` 
but I still get an underline when I type a backtick, and if I type a vowel, it adds the accent to the vowel.  Is there some new mechanism to implement dead keys?

Comment: @EoghanM run `xev`, then press the key and see what keycode comes up in the output.

Comment: @LeviH I have updated the _question_ with this info

Answer (score 0):

As well as @Levi H's answer, I believe that the new undesirable behaviour I was experiencing was some sort of extra thing that my keyboard layout was doing, which was "English (UK, intl., with dead keys)".  Another layout also produces this undesirable behaviour; "English (UK, extended, Windows)" which was likely why I missed it previously.

Anyhow the fix was to switch to `"English (UK)"` or `"English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)"`.

The new undesirable behaviour had the backtick character appear, but underlined, and then it would swallow up certain of the next characters if it could find a character which was a composite, e.g.  **`** + **w** =  `ẁ`